# Yii2 PrettyUrl and ScriptName

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app, pretty-urls

here is what i did

in web.php

```
'request' => [
      
        'parsers' => [
            'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
         ]
 ],


 'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'enableStrictParsing' => false,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
        ],
    ],
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

in browser, if the link

```
http://localhost:8888/site/web/
```

it will show data in site index but if I dive inside pages, it will show nothing,
if i added index.php the pages work and shows the data , but there is another problem
in some pages I have uploaded images and save there path in db like this:

```
   upload//63b521df1b0e0.jpg
```

it shows nothing because the link become like this :

```
http://localhost:8888/site/web/index.php/listing/upload//63b521df27bf0.jpg
```

and it should be :

```
http://localhost:8888/site/web/upload//63b521df27bf0.jpg
```

so what i missed ?

Comment: Change 'enableStrictParsing' => true in same config > main.php of module either backend or frontend or you can do it in common folder also. and place htaccess in same folder if you want it to be for backend then inside web folder or same for frontend.

Comment: @AnilKumar it's in basic so I did it in web.php , and when I did 'enableStrictParsing' => true and moved .htaccess to www directory i can't access any thing i got Not Found (#404)

Comment: yii\web\JsonParser is normally used for REST api purpose , are you doing the same? if not then try to comment out that line also and use web controller then rest controller

Comment: @AnilKumar yes even when i try to access to my api in http://localhost:8080/api/user with 
 'enableStrictParsing' => true, it gives me 404 error

Comment: https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/175/how-to-create-a-rest-api
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/yii/yii_restful_apis_action.htm
check these url might give you some help

Answer (score 0):

if you need http://localhost:8888/site/web/upload//63b521df27bf0.jpg you must contruct url as follows:

```
'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/site/web/'.$model->image_path;
```

in your version you use the relative path, but I suggest to use absolute path.